# Accessing CLI values in the runtime

Tags: substrate, parity, polkadot

I have an offchain worker that reads something via http and i would like users to be able to use different urls for it. I have a custom flag in the CLI which takes this URL (something like `./target/release/substrate --custom-url http://google.com`) but i don't know how to read it from the runtime (even in an offchain worker context) to allow the offchain worker to use this user specified url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, although it is possible to use the `offchain_localStorageSet` RPC endpoint to allow each node to maintain a different URL for the offchain worker. Have you referred to this document? https://substrate.dev/recipes/off-chain-workers/storage.html

Comment: Thanks Dan, this is perfect.